# How to give an AI controls in a video game?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pygame, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

So I made Pong using PyGame and I want to use genetic algorithms to have an AI learn to play the game. I want it to only know the location of its paddle and the ball and controls. I just don't know how to have the AI move the paddle on its own. I don't want to do like: "If the ball is above you, go up." I want it to just try random stuff until it learns what to do.

So my question is, how do I get the AI to try controls and see what works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learning Atari-[Pong](https://gym.openai.com/envs/Pong-ram-v0/) has become a standard task in reinforcement learning. For example there is the [OpenAI baselines](https://github.com/openai/baselines#example-2-dqn-on-atari) github repo implementing RL algorithms that can be plugged into various tasks.

You definitely don't need those advanced algos just to learn Pong the way you describe, but you can learn from the API they're using to separate between tasks ("environments" in reinforcement learning terms) and the AI part ("controller" or "agent"). For this, I suggest to read the [OpenAI Gymn Documentation](https://gym.openai.com/docs/) for how you would add a new Environment.

In short, you could either use some float numbers (position and velocity of ball, or two positions instead of velocity, and position of the paddle). Or you could use discrete inputs (integers, or just pixels, much harder to learn). Those inputs could be connected to a small neural network.

For the command output, the simplest thing to do is to predict a probability for moving up or down. This is a good idea because when you evaluate your controller, it will have *some* non-zero chance of scoring points, so your genetic algorithm can compare different controllers (with different weights) against each other. Just use the sigmoid function on your neural net output, and interpret it as probability.

If you initialize all your neural network weights to a good random range, you probably can get a pong player that doesn't completely suck just by trying random weights for long enough (even without a GA).

PS: if you didn't plan to use a neural network: they are really simple to implement from scratch if you only have to implement the forward-pass. E.g. if you don't implement back-propagation training, and use a GA instead to learn the weights (or an [evolution strategy](http://blog.otoro.net/2017/10/29/visual-evolution-strategies/), or just random weights). The hardest part is to find a good range for the initial random weights.

Comment: My current problem is finding a function to use that takes weights. I've never made a genetic algorithm before so I'm starting basically from scratch.

Comment: Here is an example for a [simple neural network](https://github.com/MorvanZhou/simple-neural-networks/blob/master/simple_nn.py#L28-L33) in numpy. Just add a sigmoid at the end.

Answer (score 2):

One design consideration which may be helpful is if you can provide some minimal set of display details out through another interface; and conversely allow for commands to the player paddle. For example, you could send a simple structure describing ball position and both paddles and the ball with each frame update out through a *socket* to another process. Following the same pattern, you could create a structure that is sent as a reply to that message describing how to move the player paddle. For example:

```py
# Pong Game program
import socket
import struct

# Set up server or client socket

# ... Into game loop
state = (p1_paddle_y, p2_paddle_y, ball_x, ball_y, victory_state)
# assuming pixel locations, and victory_state is -1:Loss, 0:InProgress, 1:Win

myGameStateMsg = struct.pack('>LLLLh', state[0], state[1], state[2], state[3])
sock.send(myGameStateMsg) # Sending game state to player

playerMsg = sock.recv(4) # Get player command
playerCmd = struct.unpack('i', playerMsg) 
# playerCmd is an integer describing direction & speed of paddle motion

# ... Process game state update, repeat loop
```

You could accomplish the same effect using *threads* and a transacted structure, but you'll need to consider properly guarding those structures (read-while-write problems, etc.)

Personally, I prefer the first approach (sockets & multi-processing) for stability reasons. Suppose there's some sort of bug that causes a crash; if you've already got process separation, it becomes easier to identify the source of the crash. At the thread-level, it's still possible but a little more challenging. One of the other benefits of the multi-processing approach is that you can easily set up multiple players and have the game expand (1vInGameAI, 1v1, 3v3, 4v4). Especially when you expand, you could test out different algorithms, like Q-Learning, adaptive dynamic programming, etc. and have them play each other!

### Addendum: Sockets 101

*Sockets* are a mechanism to get more than one process (i.e., a running program) to send messages to one another. These processes can be running on the same machine or across the network. In a sense, using them is like reading and writing to a file that is constantly modifying (that's the abstraction that sockets provide), but also provide *blocking calls* so that make the process wait for information to be available.

There is a lot more detail that can be discussed about sockets (like file-sockets vs network-sockets (FD vs IP); UDP vs TCP, etc.) that could easily fill multiple pages. Instead, please refer to the following tutorial about a basic setup: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html. With that, you'll have a basic understanding of what they can provide and where to go for more advanced techniques with them.

You may also want to consult the *struct* tutorial as well for introductory message packing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html. There are better ways of doing this, but you won't understand much about *how* they work and break-down without understanding structs.

Comment: You can have message-oriented separation without running multiple processes or threads.

Comment: Right, if the design satisfy functional programming constraints and/or injects training & control in between frame updates. Maintaining processing separation, though, allows for training and exercise of the learner with other systems ([sic] other implementations of Pong) that satisfy the interface OP imposes. This separation of interface and processing can allow for learning architecture independence (perhaps distributed). This design pattern is used extensively for AI competitions, research, and industry.

Comment: Forgive me but I don't understand anything you said (it's a tad advanced). I was wondering if you could maybe dumb it down for me.

Comment: I've edited my answer with references to beginners tutorials and a brief explanation of how to formulate game-state and player-action. Note, what @LieRyan said is true as well, but I've found it to be less useful in the face of experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

So you'd want as the AI input the position of the paddle, and the position of the ball. The AI output is two boolean output whether the AI should press up or down button on the next simulation step.

I'd also suggest adding another input value, the ball's velocity. Otherwise, you would've likely needed to add another input which is the location of the ball in the previous simulation step, and a much more complicated middle layer for the AI to learn the concept of velocity.

Comment: How would I go about creating a binary output? I am trying to think of some formula but I can't find a correlation.

Comment: @JacobSage Sorry, I meant boolean output, not binary. Basically, the output of an artificial neural network is going to be a floating point value, e.g. between 0 and 1, you'd want to map that value to a Boolean with an activation threshold (e.g. output greater than 0.8 means the respective button is pressed).